# Infowindow is not looping in google maps

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my project, am taking values from php database and showing as markers in google maps. I want to show service name, in each location as infowindow (Multiple service names are available for each location). I want that service name displayed in infowindow line by line in each marker location.

But when i tried to show only first service name
Following is my code, I am showing  only essential codes

```
var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
           var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
           for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
             var id = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("id");
             var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("locationName");
            // console.log(name);
             var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("locationAddress1");
             var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
             var servicename = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("serviceName");
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("locationLat")),
                  parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("locationLong")));

                  //console.log (parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("locationLong")));
             createOption(name, distance, i);
             createMarker(latlng, name, address,servicename);
             bounds.extend(latlng);
```

From above code, i will get everything from php databse,from this `servicename` ,i want to show as infowindow.

Following is the code for adding infowindow

```
function createMarker(latlng, name, address,servicename ) {
          var html = servicename;
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position: latlng,
            // label: "C",
            icon: {
      url: "{{ asset('img/new_map.png') }}"
    }

          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
          markers.push(marker);
        }
```

What is wrong with this code, if i print address or name, it will works fine.

Below is the console data am getting,for reffrence[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0JlJ.png)

Comment: your function definition for `createMarker` has 3 arguments yet you call the function with 4 arguments - `servicename` being the fourth, unnamed argument so `var html = servicename;` should be `var html = arguments[3];` perhaps... or add a named fourth argument to function definition

Comment: Sorry i have mentioned to add that here, i added servicename also as argument

Comment: Pictures of code/data are not useful.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score -1):

If you were to add a fourth named argument to the `createMarker` function you can then assign it as a property of the marker itself - which makes it quite simple to access when clicking the marker as you can use `this`

That said I do not see that you actually use the `name` nor the `address` arguments within the function itself so if again they are assigned as custom properties for the marker you can access them in the `click` event using `this` - ie: `this.name` etc

```
function createMarker( latlng, name, address, servicename ) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        html:servicename,
        map:map,
        draggable:true,
        animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position:latlng,
        name:name,
        address:address,
        icon: {
            url:"{{ asset('img/new_map.png') }}"
        }
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
        infoWindow.setContent( this.html );
        infoWindow.open( map, this );
    }.bind( marker ));

    markers.push( marker );
    return marker;
}
```

After our brief discussion and thinking further about your requirements perhaps you might try like this. As you have ( as you stated ) already added the 4th argument we can add as a custom property to each marker. In the `click` handler we can iterate over the `markers` array and compare the current markers `html` attribute/property ( you originally refer to html hence continuing to do so here ) to the `html` property of whatever marker in the array and if they match add this to the output to be displayed in the infowindow

```
function createMarker( latlng, name, address, servicename ) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        html:servicename,
        map:map,
        draggable:true,
        animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position:latlng,
        name:name,
        address:address,
        icon: {
            url:"{{ asset('img/new_map.png') }}"
        }
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function(e) {

        let data=[];
        markers.forEach( mkr=>{
            if( mkr.html==this.html ){
                data.push( mkr.html )
            }
        });

        infoWindow.setContent( data.join( '<br />' ) );
        infoWindow.open( map, this );
    }.bind( marker ));

    markers.push( marker );
    return marker;
}
```

A fully working demo ( apikey redacted ) based upon the following XML file. The `ajax` function and it's callback are simply to emulate whatever mechanism used in your code to load markers onto the map, once loaded they do not get used again - the querying of markers is done solely based upon the `markers` array.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<markers>
    <marker servicename='a' name="Kinnettles" address="B9127, Angus DD8 1, UK" lat="56.61543329027024" lng="-2.9266123065796137"/>
    <marker servicename='b' name="Nathro" address="1 Goynd Steading, Glenogil, Forfar, Angus DD8 3SW, UK" lat="56.793249595719956" lng="-2.8623101711273193"/>
    <marker servicename='a' name="ArkHill" address="3 Dryburn Cottages, Glenogilvy, Forfar, Angus DD8 1UP, UK" lat="56.57065514278748" lng="-3.0511732892761074"/>
    <marker servicename='b' name="DoddHill" address="4 Backmuir Rd, Duntrune, Tealing, Dundee, Angus DD4 0PT, UK" lat="56.54251020079966" lng="-2.9051538305053555"/>
    <marker servicename='c' name="Govals" address="B9127, Forfar, Angus DD8, UK" lat="56.582320876071854" lng="-2.9509015874633633"/>
    <marker servicename='d' name="Carsegownie" address="B9134, Forfar, Angus DD8, UK" lat="56.67951330362271" lng="-2.8062983350524746"/>
    <marker servicename='a' name="Frawney" address="Kerton Farm, Forfar, Angus DD8, UK" lat="56.56806620951482" lng="-2.9501720266113125"/>
    <marker servicename='a' name="NorthTarbrax" address="4 Nether Finlarg Farm Cottages, Forfar, Angus DD8 1XQ, UK" lat="56.57144715546598" lng="-2.92476614282225"/>
    <marker servicename='e' name="TheCarrach" address="B951, Kirriemuir, Angus DD8, UK" lat="56.6938437674986" lng="-3.131382067657455"/>
    <marker servicename='f' name="Glaxo" address="5 Meridian St, Montrose, Angus DD10 8DS, UK" lat="56.70431711148748" lng="-2.4660869436035"/>
</markers>
```

The html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Collate attributes from multiple markers to display in single InfoWindow</title>
        <style>
            #map{width:800px;height:600px;}
        </style>
        <script>
            var map;
            var markers=[];
            var infoWindow;

            function ajax(callback){
                let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                        if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 )callback(this.response)
                    }
                    xhr.open( 'GET', 'maps.xml', true );
                    xhr.send( null );
            };
            function loadmarkers(r){
                let oParser=new DOMParser();
                let oXML=oParser.parseFromString( r, 'application/xml' );
                let nodes=oXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
                for( let i=0; i < nodes.length; i++ ){
                    let latlng=new google.maps.LatLng( nodes[i].getAttribute('lat'),nodes[i].getAttribute('lng') );
                    let name=nodes[i].getAttribute('name');
                    let address=nodes[i].getAttribute('address');
                    let servicename=nodes[i].getAttribute('servicename');

                    createMarker(latlng,name,address,servicename)
                }
            };


            function createMarker( latlng, name, address, servicename  ) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    html:servicename,
                    map:map,
                    draggable:true,
                    animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    position:latlng,
                    name:name,
                    address:address
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function(e) {
                    /* query XML to find ALL nodes that have the same location */
                    let data=[
                        this.name,
                        this.address
                    ];
                    markers.forEach( mkr=>{
                        if( mkr.html==this.html ) data.push( mkr.html );
                    });

                    infoWindow.setContent( data.join( '<br />' ) );
                    infoWindow.open( map, this );
                }.bind( marker ));

                markers.push( marker );
                return marker;
            };


            function initMap(){
                let centre=new google.maps.LatLng( 56.7, -2.8 );
                let options = {
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: centre,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    disableDefaultUI: true,
                    mapTypeControl: false,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
                        mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'terrain','satellite','hybrid']
                    }
                };
                map=new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), options );
                infoWindow=new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                ajax( loadmarkers );
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxx&callback=initMap'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: The resultant map]

Comment: Now also its showing first infowindow, second and third is not displaying,,as i told one location may have multiple services

Comment: can you check the console and report if there are any errors. Added `.bind( marker )` ~ try with that changed

Comment: I see your comment above: `"Now also its showing first infowindow"` ~ does that mean that it works but that you only have a single infowindow?

Comment: If you add the XML as text I can experiment easier. I think I now understand what it is you are trying to do

Comment: I have added the picture of my xml output in question ,please look out this https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0JlJ.png

Comment: From this ouput, u can check that id 65 have multiple infowindows, (like that for all other ids)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210777/discussion-between-joshy-kaithkad-and-ramraider).

Comment: Now same service name (First service name) is repeating number of times, it has id